# How can I make the holo ProgressBar color stronger?

Tags: android

Is there any simple way to change the Holo style's `ProgressBar` forge color (just like it in Google Play)?

Comment: screen http://i.stack.imgur.com/BYFtc.png

Answer (score 0):

```
 progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

should be the solution you need.

Comment: Thanks, but just have a try, progressBar.getProgressDrawable() always return null.